# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.( Gitlab )

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab, pipeline

I have a AWS instance with Docker installed on it. And some containers are running.I have setup one Laravel project inside docker.

I can access this web application through AWS IP address as well as DNS address(GoDaddy).

I have also designed gitlab CI/CO to publish the code to AWS instance.

When I try to push the code through Gitlab pipelines, I am getting following error in pipeline.

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

I checked the docker, it is running properly. Any clues please.

.gitlab-ci.yml

> http://pastie.org/p/7ELo6wJEbFoKaz7jcmJdDp

the pipeline failing at deploy-api-staging: -> script -> scripts/ci/build

build script

> http://pastie.org/p/1iQLZs5GqP2m5jthB4YCbh

deploy script

> http://pastie.org/p/2ho6ElfN2iWRcIZJjQGdmy

Comment: There are a lot of cases can happen by that error. Can you tell me what you do in the pipeline?

Comment: I am building the image and publishing it on aws , I am attaching the gitlab code in question

Comment: Does you Gitlab CI agent has Docker in it? 
Gitlab CI need a agent to run. I think your agent does not have Docker

Comment: Oh, I see , checking the same. Can you give me more details. Like how to check it and how can I set it.

Comment: Where did you install the Gitlab CI runner? Check that instance

Comment: I registered the gitlab runner from AWS instance. I logged in through SSH cmd and after configuring project, I registered the runner

Comment: Did you specify the right user for the right runner? If you use EC2, in need to be ec2-user or ubuntu, or custom user with root permission

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238342/discussion-between-jay-vyas-and-ash-blake).

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question into a different question is against policy when doing so invalidates one or more answers, even if the original question isn't what you really intended to ask. Your edit here invalidated an answer. Users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I've reverted your edit. You're *encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps linking this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you have directly installed and registered the GitLab runner on your EC2 instance.

I think the problem is that you haven't already given permissions to your GitLab Runner user to use Docker.

From the official Docker documentation:

> The Docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can only access it using sudo. The Docker daemon always runs as the root user.
>
> If you don’t want to preface the docker command with sudo, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the Docker daemon starts, it creates a Unix socket accessible by members of the docker group.

Well, GitLab Runners use the user `gitlab-runner` by default when they're running any CI/CD Pipeline and that user won't use `sudo` (neither it should be in the sudoers file!) so we have to correctly configure it.

First of all, create a Docker group on the EC2 where the GitLan Runner is registered:

```sh
sudo groupadd docker
```

Then, we are going to add the user `gitlab-runner` to that group:

```sh
sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
```

And we are going to verify that the `gitlab-runner` user actually has access to Docker:

```sh
sudo -u gitlab-runner -H docker info
```

Now your Pipelines should be able to access without any problem to the Unix socket under `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

#### Additional Steps if using Docker Runners

If you're using the Docker executor in your runner, you have to now mount that Unix socket on the Docker image you're using.

```
[[runners]]
    url = "https://gitlab.com/"
    token = REGISTRATION_TOKEN
    executor = "docker"
    [runners.docker]
        tls_verify = false
        image = "docker:19.03.12"
        privileged = false
        disable_cache = false
        volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
```

Take special care of the contents in the `volume` clause.

Comment: Hey dude , tried the solution. Still it is failing with same error

Comment: Have you configured a different user for the GitLab runner than `gitlab-runner`? What does it says if you change to `gitlab-runner` in your EC2 and you try to access to Docker manually?

Comment: when I run cmd , I am getting following info , http://pastie.org/p/3aN2wu4LDVAJf4BFnYVQ7p

Comment: No, I have configured same user

Comment: Error changed now, time="2021-10-20T04:21:09-07:00" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
context canceled

Comment: Are you mounting the socket to the Docker runner image? Can I see your runners configuration?

I added an extra step for configuring the Runner, since I already supposed you had it correctly configured and it was just a permissions problem.

Comment: I think I haven't mounted. I have created gitlab runner using cmd "gitlab-runner register" and selected docker as executer. Can you give some details like where to run the code you have given please

Comment: You can change the configuration of a GitLab Runner by modifying the `config.toml` file. Since you're in a EC2 instance, I guess it will be in `/etc/gitlab-runner/` if the runner is executed as root or under `~/.gitlab-runner/` if you registered with a non-root user. Check the documentation in https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html

Comment: [[runners]]
  name = "industrydigital/buildbox-php:0.3.0"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = ""
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "industrydigital/buildbox-php:0.3.0"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0

Comment: Effectively, you don't have the Unix socket mounted on your runner. Add this to the volumes array: `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. 

PD: Edit your comment and delete the token.

Comment: btw , I have the config.toml file at "/home/ubuntu/.gitlab-runner" location on EC2 instance. Hope this is ok

Comment: That means you're executing the runner with your `ubuntu` user. There is no problem.

Comment: Changed, but still no success. config.toml should refresh automatically after changes, correct ?

Comment: When I run , find ~/ -type f -name "docker.sock" , I dont see any path to docker.sock file

Comment: Why are you looking for the `docker.sock` under the user folder? It's always in /var/run/docker.sock Also, regarding the configuration, that one is checked automatically each 3 seconds.

Comment: got it.Everything seems ok. Not sure, why I am still getting the error.

Comment: Try to run `whoami` and the permissions for `/var/run/docker.sock` when you're in the Pipeline. Let's see if there's a problem of other nature.

Comment: Not success-ed yet , is it related to git lab-registry ?

Comment: No, this is a problem of misconfiguration between your host machine, the runner and the image using to run the Pipeline; since you can launch the image that means that at least Docker is properly configured in the host machine. If you still have problems with the permissions and configuration, maybe you should just try a docker-in-docker solution: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-the-docker-image-docker-in-docker

Comment: Please Jay, if you already resolved your problem, put the question to the original status and mark which was the solution. If you have additional problems feel free to put them in different questions, since maybe your original problem is shared among readers.